# cocostudio: How do I use exported scene file. Does CCSceneReader work for anyone?

Tags: cross-platform, cocos2d-x, cocostudio

I created a new scene in cocostudio and exported it. That export included a json file for the scene and a couple other directories with the images and so forth. I installed cocostudio and cocos2dx 3.0 fresh today.

I keep running in to this like of code:

```
CCSSceneReader::sharedSceneReader()->createNodeWithSceneFile("your_scene.json");
```

I've seen it on the [cocos2dx help docs](http://upyun.cocimg.com/CocoStudio/helpdoc/v1.0.0.0/en/index.html)(bottom of the page) and a few other places online.

The problem is that no class called CCSceneReader comes with cocos2dx and I am not sure where to find it.

I'm open to other means of using the cocostudio export that don't use CCSceneReader but I have yet to find anything that works. Has anybody got this working  successfully?

Comment: Figured it out eventually, just a result of being unfamiliar with cocos2dx.

If anyone was wondering, you need to remove the "CCS" from scene reader and also add "cocostudio::" if you're not already using the cocostudio namespace (which by default, you're not"

I also needed to add "#include "editor-support/cocostudio/CocoStudio.h" to my header file.

So, by default your new cocos2dx project isn't using cocostudio. You need to add it

Comment: Ahh man I was wondering about this, too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[erparker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470606/erparker) left this answer in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844363/cocostudio-how-do-i-use-exported-scene-file-does-ccscenereader-work-for-anyone#comment34848484_22844363)

> Figured it out eventually, just a result of being unfamiliar with cocos2dx. If anyone was wondering, you need to remove the "CCS" from scene reader and also add "cocostudio::" if you're not already using the cocostudio namespace (which by default, you're not" I also needed to add "#include "editor-support/cocostudio/CocoStudio.h" to my header file. So, by default your new cocos2dx project isn't using cocostudio. You need to add it